# Use react-native-popup-dialog as Alert.alert

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-dialog

I am using Alert.alert("") to display message, but I would like to change it to use react-native-popup-dialog because message of alert can not be aligned and very limited expression.

For example, my current function is as follows.
And I would like to use react-native-popup-dialog, but from an example, it can be used inside of render function.

Is there any way to use react-native-popup-dialog?

```
displayMessage: function(message)
{
    Alert.alert(`${message}`);    // current
    // Dialog.???(`${message}`);  // future
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using react-native-popup-dialog?

Comment: No, I am trying to use, but all example code is using <View /> or <Dialog> ... </Dialog>.

Comment: Then that is how you use that library. You can save that in a variable, but it can't act as a class like `Alert` because there is no implementation for that. One way to do it is to always have it in `render`, but only show that based on a state variable

Comment: @Andreas Thank a lot Andreas, I thought there might be some way. I tried to find a way by googling but I couldn't. Thank you again.

Comment: Another note, as far as I know, usually most of those 3rd party libraries can only be used in this way (they can't act as a class). The reason is because, if you look at their implementation, they are just customizing and composing the existing elements in react native library into the custom elements that they provide.